# How to enable AOF on already running Redis without data loss?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis instance running with `snapshot` enabled, and so it the data is being persisted to `RDB` file as expected. The `RDB` file has some 2GB of data.

I want to enable `AOF`. So the first way I tried is this:
I stopped my Redis server, enabled `AOF` and restarted Redis. I found that all my previous data which was backed up in `RDB` file did not load up because once `AOF` is enabled, Redis loads `AOF` file to recover data (which in this case is empty, since I just enabled it).

So my question is, how can I enable `AOF` after some data is already written to Redis and thus persisted in `RDB` file?

I know we can enable `AOF` without having to stop Redis from `redis-cli` itself via `CONFIG SET` command and my data will remain in Redis's memory, but what about the already existing data in memory? If my Redis server stops/fails and then restarts, the `AOF` file will only have partial data and there will be data loss.

**Example scenario:**

**Day1**: I have started my redis with snapshot enabled.

**Day2**: I have some 5GB of data in Redis memory and the same 5GB in `RDB` file.

**Day3**: I enable `AOF` via `redis-cli` without restarting redis.

**Day4**: AOF file received some 500 commands, and then Redis fails.

I need to now restart my Redis and when I restart the data will be recovered from AOF file. But `AOF` file has commands only after Day3. What will happen to the 5GB of data that was previously in my Redis memory till Day2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, how can I enable AOF after some data is already written to Redis and thus persisted in RDB file?

YES. You can use `config set appendonly yes` to enable AOF.

> but what about the already existing data in memory? If my Redis server stops/fails and then restarts, the AOF file will only have partial data and there will be data loss.

Once you use `config set` command to enable AOF, Redis triggers an AOF rewrite job in the background to write all data in memory to AOF. So the newly created AOF file has all data, NOT partial data, i.e. no data loss.